# How to 2-way bind a ngModel with a 2D array?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

I have an array of events, such that some events may have filters, some may not. To visualize this:

```
[
  {
    type: 'event1',
    filters: [ { name: 'filter1' }, { name: 'filter2' } ]
  }
  {
    type: 'event2',
    filters: [ { name: 'filter1' } ]
  }
  {
    type: 'event3',
    filters: [ ]
  }
]
```

I've tried to make a two way binding on filter input field to get it's value, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events">
...
  <div *ngFor="let filter of event.filters">
    <input id="{{event.type}}.{{filter.name}}" [(ngModel)]="filters[event.type][filter.name]" />
  </div>
</div>
```

,while in **component.ts** I've declared `filters: any = [];`.
All I get is [image: undefined error], which is presumably connected with lack of filters in some events. Is there any way to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to bind to the `name` property of the `filters` array, the binding should look like following

```html
<div *ngFor="let event of events">
  ...
  <div *ngFor="let filter of event.filters">
    <input id="{{event.type}}.{{filter.name}}" [(ngModel)]="filter.name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I do so, the input value (text inside input) of each filter will simply contain the filter name.

Comment: @m.f: Which property do you wish to bind the `<input>` to?

Comment: As a result I would like to be able to get the *filter* array of input values in such a way, that I could access it eg. `filters[event1][filter1]` gives me the text value from event1 -> filter1 text input field.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Based on your object, you could access `filters[0][name]`. I don't understand what you mean by `filters[event1][filter1]`.

Comment: Thing is, I think *ngModel* does not allow me to 2-way bind **events that don't have filters at all** - hence the *undefined* error.

Comment: If the array posted in the question is called `events`, do you have a `filters` property in the component controller? The binding `[(ngModel)]="filters[event.type][filter.name]"` looks for a variable `filters` in the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233889/discussion-between-m-f-and-michael-d).